# Why is regex.exec() return type is a boolean?

Tags: javascript, regex, return-type

I'm quite new to javascript and have an issue on regex
According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) documentation page, the regex.exec() function should return either an array or null if there's no match.

> if the match succeeds, the exec() method returns an array and updates properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.
>   If the match fails, the exec() method returns null.

why then in my code, the result of exec() is either a **boolean** or **null**?

```
function matchHTMLsymbols(str)
  var pattern = /&|<|>|"|' /g;
  var arr;
  while ((arr = pattern.exec(str) !== null)) {
    console.log(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `!==` have higher precedence than `=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `arr` isn't the result of `exec`, it's the result of `!==` (which should be either `true` or `false`).

In other words, `x = y !== z` parses as `x = (y !== z)`, not `(x = y) !== z`.

You probably meant to write

```
while ((arr = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
```

instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that since all arrays are truthy, the whole thing can be simplified into `while(arr = pattern.exec(str))` and the entire problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You should add one pair of parentheses in your `while` loop:

```js
function matchHTMLsymbols(str) {
  var pattern = /&|<|>|"|' /g,
      arr;
      
  while (((arr = pattern.exec(str)) !== null)) {
    console.log(arr);
  }
}

matchHTMLsymbols('foo<bar"baz&');
```

Comment: Look at melpomene's answer. Then look at your answer. Back to melpomene's answer. Your answer is not melpomene's answer. But don't worry, if you actually take a moment to explain *why* a change is needed, like melpomene, then you, like melpomene, might also receive upvotes and have a score like melpomene's.

Comment: Actually, when I posted this answer, there was no `while ((arr = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {` in melpomene's answer...